# Forma validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have an html form that has 6 input boxes that should add up to 100. If they don't add put to 100 or there are inputs left empty, alerts should appear when the button is clicked. So far I can get the alert if the total isn't right, but not for an empty field.

HTML

```
        <fieldset>

             <input  type="text" name="qty" oninput="findTotal()" id="qty1" class="hvr-pop" required/>   

             <input  type="text" name="qty" oninput="findTotal()" id="qty2" class="hvr-pop" required/>    

             <input  type="text" name="qty" oninput="findTotal()" id="qty3" class="hvr-pop" required/>    

             <input  type="text" name="qty" oninput="findTotal()" id="qty4" class="hvr-pop" required/>    

             <input  type="text" name="qty" oninput="findTotal()" id="qty5" class="hvr-pop" required/>    

             <input  type="text" name="qty" oninput="findTotal()" id="qty6" class="hvr-pop" required/>    

       </fieldset>    

       <button type="button" class="weightageButton" onclick="validateTotal()">TOTAL WEIGHTAGE</button>
       <output type="text" name="total" id="total" class="hvr-pop" readonly value="Must total 100"></output>
```

Javascript

```
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value) === null || score > 100 || score < 100) {

            alert("Please make sure each weightage is filled in and the total adds up to 100.");
            $('#form1').find('input').val('');
            $('#form1').find('#total').val('');
            return false;
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text fields has any Character value then `parseInt(arr[i].value) === null` will not work , as you are expecting .
The isNaN() function determines whether a value is an illegal number . Number.isNan() does not convert the values to a Number, and will not return true for any value that is not of the type Number. 
Instead of `parseInt(arr[i].value) === null` you should use  `isNaN(parseInt(arr[i].value))` .

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `parseInt()` for empty string returns `NaN`, not a `NULL`. You should replace current check to this:

```
    if (isNaN(parseInt(arr[i].value)) || ... ) { ... }
```